Propagation of Sansevieria – Is My Cutting Going to Succeed?
I accidentally broke a leaf off my Dracaena trifasciata 'Laurentii' (Sansevieria) while repotting it. So, I decided to try propagating it. I let the leaf dry and callous for four weeks before planting it in a small pot with appropriate soil for a Sansevieria. It’s been three months now, and there hasn't been much change in the cutting. Here are some photos of my plant:


Is this a good sign, and do I still have a chance of success with this propagation? Should I continue waiting, or is there something I should adjust in terms of care?

Why a month? Snake plants need one day to dry. Could you bear to unpot and peek at the great roots and emerging baby? Also, I divide such cuttings in four.

This was my first time propagating, and I found advice suggesting to wait a month to let the cutting form a callous, to protect it from infections and rot. I haven’t checked the roots yet, but I might unpot it to take a look soon. Thanks for the tip about dividing the cutting!

I see no advantage to uprooting it as any root system that has formed is likely to be fragile and not particularly tolerant to soil disturbance. If it's rotting below the soil, you'll know soon. The fact that it still looks healthy now is a strong indication that it's fine and to keep doing what you're doing.

Its a good sign that it has not died.  I would just persevere.  While its green (and not dried looking), it is still alive.
You probably wont see any new leaf growth for a while as it has to build a root system first.
